# Firewall and VPN functionalities for a Cisco ISR4321 V/K9

Tags: cisco, vpn, cisco-commands, acl, cisco-isr

I would like to know if I can setup ACLs with the `access-list` command with a `Cisco ISR4321 V/K9`.
Are there restrictions (in comparison with a `Cisco ISR4321 VSEC/K9`)?
Note the `SEC` part in the reference.

Can I setup a `VPN IPsec ISAKMP` between a `Cisco ISR4321 V/K9` and another router like a `Cisco 887VA SEC/K9` router?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can setup ACL on any Cisco IOS device, this is a base feature.

Regarding the VPN, to my surprise, for the IRS4321, according to [this datasheet](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/4000-series-integrated-services-routers-isr/datasheet-c78-732542.html) it seems you need the Security (SEC) feature bundle to use IPsec VPN.

[image]

The Cisco 88VA SEC/K9  has Advance Security as default feature set and so supports IPsec VPN (see table 3 and 4 in [this datasheet](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/800-series-routers/data_sheet_c78-613481.html))

Comment: Thank you. I just do not understand why this is surprising to you. Can you explain? Is it surprising for an ISR?

Comment: Because in most Cisco devices I have worked with, IPsec VPN is a base feature that doen't require a specific bundle. And ISR stand for "Integrated Service Router". The fact that such a basic service is not integrated strikes me.

Comment: Well, not everyone says it is not integrated... that is the problem. There is an uncertainty.

Comment: to further add to the uncertainty, on some Cisco platforms, a service normally activated by a license actually works without the license. You technically can use it but legally can't.